# Maintaining state and count of checkboxes while paging in a GridView control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview on a aspx page with pagination enabled.
This gridview contains some data fields from a database and a check-box for each row.

I started out wondering whether the check-box option will be remembered if I rebind the datasource before looping through all the rows, but quickly determined that even going from one page to the next page then back again the check-box option is lost.

To persist the check box checked status I have tried a custom implementation in this tutorial: http://aspalliance.com/774_Maintaining_State_of_CheckBoxes_While_Paging_in_a_GridView_Control.all

I want to count the number of checkboxes which are checked on my asp.net page and if the count = 5 then to change the button state from disabled to enabled, but when I change page in Gridview are not counted the selected rows of the grid in previous page.

My code it's below.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

```
private void RememberOldValues()
{
    ArrayList categoryIDList = new ArrayList();
    int index = -1;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        index = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
        bool result = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked;

        if (Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"] != null)
            categoryIDList = (ArrayList)Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"];
        if (result)
        {
            if (!categoryIDList.Contains(index))
                categoryIDList.Add(index);
        }
        else
            categoryIDList.Remove(index);
    }
    if (categoryIDList != null && categoryIDList.Count > 0)
        Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"] = categoryIDList;
}

private void RePopulateValues()
{
    ArrayList categoryIDList = (ArrayList)Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"];
    if (categoryIDList != null && categoryIDList.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            int index = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
            if (categoryIDList.Contains(index))
            {
                CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");
                myCheckBox.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}



protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    RememberOldValues();
    GridViewBind();
    GridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    RePopulateValues();
}


protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    CheckBox chkTest = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow grdRow = (GridViewRow)chkTest.NamingContainer;

    int count = 0;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            count++;
            grdRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        }
    }

    if (count == 5)
    {
        btnUpdate.Enabled = true;
        btnUpdate.CssClass = "enabledImageButton";
    }
    else
    {
        btnUpdate.Enabled = false;
        btnUpdate.CssClass = "disabledImageButton";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a private property to read arralist from session, to avoid calling it again and again.

```
ArrayList SelectedCategories
{
    get
    {
        ArrayList categoryIDList;
        if (Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"] != null)
            categoryIDList = (ArrayList)Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"];
        else
        {
            categoryIDList = new ArrayList();
            Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"] = categoryIDList;
        }
        return categoryIDList;
    }
}
```

Then in your Checkbox changed event you can change the code to access the stored selection array list.

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    CheckBox chkTest = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow grdRow = (GridViewRow)chkTest.NamingContainer;
    int index = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[grdRow.RowIndex].Value;
    if (chkTest.Checked)
    {
        if (!SelectedCategories.Contains(index))
            SelectedCategories.Add(index);
        grdRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    }
    else
    {
        if (SelectedCategories.Contains(index))
            SelectedCategories.Remove(index);
        grdRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }
    if (SelectedCategories.Count >= 5)
    {
        btnUpdate.Enabled = true;
        btnUpdate.CssClass = "enabledImageButton";
    }
    else
    {
        btnUpdate.Enabled = false;
        btnUpdate.CssClass = "disabledImageButton";
    }
}
```